# How to get a to and fro travelling results for Prolog_2

Tags: recursion, prolog

i have asked regarding the questions about travelling,

```
byCar(auckland,hamilton).
byCar(hamilton,raglan).
byCar(valmont,saarbruecken).
byCar(valmont,metz).

byTrain(metz,frankfurt).
byTrain(saarbruecken,frankfurt).
byTrain(metz,paris).
byTrain(saarbruecken,paris).

byPlane(frankfurt,bangkok).
byPlane(frankfurt,singapore).
byPlane(paris,losAngeles).
byPlane(bangkok,auckland).
byPlane(losAngeles,auckland).
```

and i have amended to this:

```
connect(X,Y,byCar):- byCar(X,Y) ; byCar(Y,X).
connect(X,Y,byTrain):- byTrain(X,Y) ; byTrain(Y,X).
connect(X,Y,byPlane):- byPlane(X,Y) ; byPlane(Y,X).

travel(X,Y):-X\=Y,travelLoop(X,Y,Passed).  
travelLoop(X,Y,Passed):-connect(X,Thru,byCar);
      connect(X,Thru,byTrain);
      connect(X,Thru,byPlane);
      \+memberchk(Thru,Passed),travelLoop([Thru|Passed],Y,Thru). 
travelLoop(X,Y,Path):- X=Y. 
travel(X,Y):-travel_Path(X,Y,[X]), 
      travel_Path(Y,X,[Y]) -> true ; wrong. 
wrong:- writeln('Wrong travel input, please try again.'), nl.
```

it works well. Can i just ask one more favour, which is to be able to show all alternative travelling path, to and fro. Just managed to get it for one way only.

(c)

```
travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byTrain(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):-byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y,go(X,Z,W)):-travel(X,Z,go(X,Z)),travel(Z,Y,W).

findall(X,travel(A,B,X),List),nl,
      writelist(List).

writelist([]).
writelist([L|Lt]):-write(L),nl,writelist(Lt).
```

(d)

```
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,car)):-byCar(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,train)):-byTrain(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Y,plane)):-byPlane(X,Y).
travel1(X,Y,go(X,Z,V,W)):-travel1(X,Z,go(X,Z,V)),travel1(Z,Y,W).

findall(Y,travel1(A,B,Y),List1),nl,
      writelist(List1).  

writelist([]).
writelist([L|Lt]):-write(L),nl,writelist(Lt).
```

any suggestions please?

The output for (c), if i enter `from=valmont, to=paris`, it gives this:

```
go(valmont,saarbruecken,go(saarbruecken,paris))
go(valmont,metz,go(metz,paris))
```

Same situation for (d).

```
go(valmont,saarbruecken,car,go(saarbruecken,paris,train))
go(valmont,metz,car,go(metz,paris,train))
```

Comment: Your code has a lot pf problems. I would suggest to cleanup your question, posting - well formatted - **actual** code yielding **at least** some result.

Comment: so sorry everyone. Was in a rush as in i couldn't figure out why it didnt work right. Have already labelled them. @mbratch

Comment: your question should be self-contained. You can't expect us to collect your code from bits and pieces in your previous question, your answer there, and this new question. Even if we did, how are we to be sure we did it right? Post here the file that you run, ***in full***. Do it in one code block and it won't take up too much screen space (will show up as a window with a scroll bar to its side). Show us the command you run, and the results you're getting, and the results that you wanted to get. As it is right now, I doubt you'll get this question answered in its current form. :(